# Verbo "durare": ausiliare "avere" o "essere"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, auxiliary-verb

Ho consultato la [voce "durare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/durare/) in cerca di esempi di uso dell'ausiliare "essere" con questo verbo. Sono rimasta perplessa quando ho letto questa spiegazione:

> *la guerra è durata sei anni*; *è durato a piovere per un’ora* (ma: *ha durato a piovere per varî giorni*, in base alla regola di solito seguita per l’uso dell’ausiliare con i verbi impersonali relativi a fenomeni atmosferici);

A quale regola si riferisce? Perché si dice "è durato a piovere per un’ora", ma "ha durato a piovere per varî giorni"? Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Non pretendo di conoscere l'Italiano meglio della Treccani, ma devo dire che *ha durato a piovere per un'ora* mi suona veramente male (in generale l'uso della locuzione *durare a* mi suona scorretto o quantomeno arcaico). Sconsiglio vivamente di usare queste forme nella pratica. Aspetto con interesse una risposta da qualcuno più qualificato di me.

Comment: Mai sentito o letto  "è durato a piovere" e per quel che vale l'espressione non risulta presente in Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A8+durato+a+piovere+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: @Josh61 Idem per "ha durato a piovere": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ha+durato+a+piovere&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url= Da un analisi dei risultati direi che si tratta di un uso arcaico di *durare* come sinonimo di *continuare*

Answer (score 2):

La regola è menzionata in Serianni, Grammatica italiana, capitolo 11, paragrafo 37. In breve, i verbi atmosferici vorrebbero avere.

Nei paragrafi 34-36 troviamo la risposta all'esistenza di entrambe le versioni: la scelta dell'ausiliare con i verbi intransitivi è notevolmente variabile. Non si è ancora trovata una legge che spieghi in modo soddisfacente ogni singolo caso ("ben pochi, dunque, i punti fermi"). È probabile che alcuni parlanti abbiano seguito la prima strada (essere) in quanto in genere il verbo vuole "essere" se può essere usato come attributo ("[Con lei ho avuto un flirt durato una sera](http://goo.gl/JfJsBV)"); altri hanno seguito la seconda (avere) per la regola suddetta (ma personalmente non ho mai sentito usare questo costrutto).